# Teamviewer VPN not connecting until I open "Network and Sharing Center"

Tags: windows-10, vpn, teamviewer

This is the problem I have with Teamviewer VPN on a remote computer running Windows 10: 
When I try to open a VPN connection from another computer to my remote Windows 10 computer, I cannot ping to it. If I run the command ipconfig in the remote computer there is no connection nor IP assigned to the VPN adapter. But if I manualy open the "Network and Sharing Center" in the remote computer and try again to ping to it, then it works, and running again ipconfig shows an IP assigned. So opening "Network and Sharing Center" triggers the VPN adapter to assign an IP an really make the connection.
After that, if I close the VPN connection and close "Network and Sharing Center" and try to open a Teamviewer VPN again it works as it should without opening again "Network and Sharing Center". But eventually after some unknown time if I try to connect again it won't work and I'll have to open again "Network and Sharing Center" to make it work.

Anybody knows what can be wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with a different VPN (Palo Alto's GlobalProtect).